# FPGA register initialization

Tags: fpga, vhdl, verilog, synthesis

I have to ask and understand it once and for all because I encountered a few opinions about this subject:

When I'm designing FPGA with Verilog or VHDL there is any meaning to:

```
Verilog ->  initial block  
VHDL    ->  `:=`
```

in the `signal` declaration or does the FPGA synthesizer ignore these code parts completely?

For example, if I want the register "blabla" in startup to have the value 0101, is this the correct code:

```
Verilog ->   
reg [3:0] blabla;  
initial blabla := 4'b0101;

VHDL ->  
signal blabla std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0101";
```

If I want to initialize a register what is the right way to do it? Inside process / always block under the reset logic?

What ifI don't want to reset the value of the register but I do want to initialize the register?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> the FPGA synthesizer ignores these code parts completely?

Both Quartus (Altera/Intel) and Vivado/ISE (Xilinx) respect initial statements for synthesis (as do some others). You **can** use them to set default (power-on) values for registers and memories.

There are as ever limitations.

- Not all FPGA families support setting a power-up value for a register. In some devices all registers will always power up to zero. For such devices, if power up to 1 is required, the synthesis tools will instead do bubble pushing - the output and input of the register are inverted, such that powering up to 0 will give you a 1 on the output.
- Not all FPGA families support initialising memory cells (e.g. block ram). For those that don't, your only option is to effectively store the defaults in some other location (e.g. external ROM/Flash, or in LUTs) and copy the values in one by one after the reset is cleared.
- Initial blocks only set the power-on value (where supported), not the reset value. You will still likely want a reset signal, during which you can set the value for the register. In fact if you know you will have a reset signal that is asserted before the registers are used, you can simply forego the initial block, and just use the reset to set a default value.
- Some synthesis tools will try to infer the power-on value if a register has a reset signal. If you set the value of the register to 1 during reset, the tool will detect this and try to set the power-on value of the register to 1 if possible.

---

Note: "power-on" in this context is the point at which the FPGA enters user mode. For CPLDs with instant-on, this is nominally when the power supplies turn on. For SRAM FPGAs this is usually after configuration (with partial reconfiguration the lines can blur).

Comment: In most FPGAs (SRAM-based) this won't set values after power-up, but after configuration.

Comment: @user_1818839 fair point.

Answer (score 0):

#### Can you?  Yes.  Should you rely on them?  Probably not...

The main issue for these is that they initialise registers immediately on startup, and not thereafter.

In a practical FPGA design though, this isn't usually how it works.  You need the device to be held in its reset state until the rest of the system is ready (and in particular, until power supplies stabilise).  You also need to device to be able to reset at other times (for example at watchdog timeout).

To handle all of these cases, you need some kind of "if (reset_active)" condition in every   block which maintains state, explicitly setting the registers to the appropriate reset values.  So it doesn't matter what you do with register initialisers, because that initialiser will immediately be stomped by your reset condition.